# Xamarin - File not found when attempting to share

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to share a downloaded file using Sharing Intents. The following quote opens the sharing menu, but when I try to share to a picture viewer, I get a file not found error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void OpenShareIntent(string fileName) {
        var myIntent = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionView);
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath, fileName);
        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(filePath);


        myIntent.SetData(uri);
        myIntent.SetType(Java.Net.URLConnection.GuessContentTypeFromName(filePath));

        Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(myIntent, "Choose an App"));
}
```

Comment: Are you targeting Android 24+? Then you need to implement a `FileProvider`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Comment: Yep that was it. Thank you!

Comment: Good! I added an answer which you can accept to help other users :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to implement a `FileProvider` since you are targeting Android 24+: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider